# Msg 102, Level 15, state 1 Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'n' 

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, syntax-error, osql

I have the following query which I am running using a batch file. In the batch file I use the following syntax:

```
echo populating Application table with values...

SET "installFile=%sqlDir%\Install\DataFiles\Insert_ApplicationNames.sql"

OSQL /n /i "%installFile%" /d%db% /U%user% /P%pswd% /S%serv%
echo
echo populated Application table with values in Insert_ApplicationNames.sql
echo
```

The sql shown below runs without any errors when executed from the SQL Management Studio, but it keeps erroring out when run as a part of the batch script. Could some one help me find what I may be doing wrong here?

Also, the rows do get inserted, but our nightly QA install breaks because of the error thrown by the batch script.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Application WHERE name = '')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Application
    (Name)
    VALUES
    ('')
END
GO
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Application WHERE name = 'App1.exe')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Application
    (Name)
    VALUES
    ('App1.exe')
END
GO
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Application WHERE name = 'App2.exe')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Application
    (Name)
    VALUES
    ('App2.exe')
END
```

Comment: Is this the exact script in `Insert_ApplicationNames.sql`?

Comment: yes, only diff being that there are 2 more app names that I am inserting along with the above 3

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server do you use?? As of 2005, you should be using the `sqlcmd` utility rather than the osql...

Comment: Do you have any insert triggers on your Application table?  Your error message could be coming from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GO` is the (default) batch separator keyword in Management Studio, but it isn't a *real* SQL keyword (i.e., SQL Server doesn't recognize it).

Remove those from your script -- in the script you've provided, they are irrelevant anyway -- and you should be good to, um, go.

Answer (score 0):

Curious whether your variables should be right up against the switches. Try this?

```
OSQL -n -i "%installFile%" -d %db% -U %user% -P %pswd% -S %serv%
```

What happens when you use the line above with your known good values right in the command?

```
OSQL -n -i "C:\foo.sql" -d MyDB -U MyUser -P MyPwd -S MyServ
```

Comment: Tried both your suggestions, but still the same error. Also, many other sql scripts are being executed along with this using the same syntax and all of them execute correctly